# Problemas con TextView en Android Studio 3.0.1

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Hola estoy usando [Android Studio 3.0.1](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html?hl=es-419) y el TextView me lo marca en *rojo* como error, dice

> Function invocation 'TextView(...)' expected None of the following
>   functions can be called with the arguments supplied. (Context!)
>   defined in android.widget.TextView (Context!, AttributeSet!)
>   defined in android.widget.TextView (Context!, AttributeSet!,
>   Int) defined in android.widget.TextView (Context!,
>   AttributeSet!, Int, Int) defined in android.widget.TextVie

El operador  =   marca

> Expecting an element

Y al llamar a la variable miTexto para implementar el método setText() marca

> Unresolved reference: miText

Acá el código del MainActivity.kt

```
package holamundo.programming.app.tuto.com.myapplication

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView miTexto = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

        miTexto.setText("He cambiado");

    }
}
```

Realmente vi varios vídeos y leí en varias paginas pero todos hacen lo mismo y no me funciona, sera la versión del IDE??

Comment: Has probado a hacerlo así directamente 'miTexto.text = "He cambiado" .Sabrás que estás utilizando Kotlin y a la hora de hacer la referencia al objeto lo estás haciendo con java.

Comment: Agregue una respuesta, en realidad estas uando Kotlin y no Java por lo tanto es diferente la forma de obtener la referencia del TextView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que estas usando [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/) y no `Java`, en este caso debes obtener la referencia del `TextView` de esta forma:

```
 val miTexto: TextView  = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView) as TextView
 miTexto.text = "He cambiado"
```

Tu proyecto fue creado con soporte [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/) por lo tanto debes programar en `Kotlin` :)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: **Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.

Comment: Muchas gracias me funciono, entonces si no hubiese tildado Kotlin no hubiese tenido este problema?

Comment: Que bien que funciono!,exacto,  si no agregas soporte Kotlin puedes programar como lo realizaste inicialmente que es con Java.

Answer (score 0):

Estas utilizando Kotlin en tu proyecto, por lo tanto no es necesario hacer el cast del elemento al cual estas haciendo referencia.

si por ejemplo en tu activity en el XML tienes un widget como el siguiente:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/texto_modificar"
        tools:text="Mi Texto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

y quieres modificar el texto, lo puedes hacer sin necesidad de hacer el cast que se hace en java, simplemente llamando el id puedes acceder a todas las propiedades de ese widget o elemento.

para cambiar el texto, si por ejemplo tienes una variable en tu archivo `kt` y quieres pasárselo a tu widget puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
val miVariable = "Hola"

texto_modificar.text = miVariable  // opcion con variable
texto_modificar.text = "aqui va tu nuevo texto"   // opcion donde escribes directamente el texto
```

Recuerda que también es mejor manejar todos los string que son asignados directamente a las vistas desde el archivo `strings.xml` que se encuentra en el directorio `/res/values/` de tu proyecto.